# How do I calculate linear trend for a multi-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, trend

I've got a 3d array of shape (time,latitude,longitude). I'd like to calculate the linear trend at each lon/lat point. 
I know I can simply loop over all points and use spicy.stats.linregress at each point. However, that gets quite slow for large arrays.

The scipy function "detrend" can calculate and remove linear trends for n-dimensional arrays, and is really fast. But I can't find any method to just calculate the trends.

Does anyone know of a fast way to calculate slope, intercept, r value and p value for each point on a large grid?

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Joakim

Comment: Here's the source of `scipy.signal.detrend`: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L1765

Answer (score 1):

I would look into `numpy.polyfit` but I'm not sure what performance gain it has over `scipy.stats.linregress`.
It's pretty fast from my experience. You might have to do some math on your own to get r and p values from residuals and covariance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

slope(m) and intercept(c) can easily be calculated using signal.detrend. Please check the code below for a signal y

```
    detrended_y=signal.detrend(y, axis=0, type='linear')
    trend_y=y-detrended_y
    trend_c=trend_y[0,:,:] # intercept
    trend_m=trend_y[1,:,:]-trend_y[0,:,:] #slope
```